# The square brackets in b'BODY[] have no content and my email body is None. Are these 2 connected?

Tags: python, email

I had a problem getting data from emails. Solved that after a lot of reading, but I am still intrigued as to why my email body is **None**. I can see my email perfectly well in any email program. I suspect it has been transmogrified into an html mail.

Using:

```
> msg = server.fetch([6594], 'RFC822').items()
```

I got an email as raw message.

The raw message is long and complex, I won't post it all, but the first part is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {6594: {b'SEQ': 142, b'BODY[]': b'X-QQ-mid: esmtp2t1541024468t23l1413e\r\nReceived: from [192.168.1.6] (unknown [183.209.152.106])\r\n\tby esmtp4.qq.com (ESMTP) with SMTP id 0\r\n\tfor <myEmail@foxmail.com>; Thu, 01 Nov 2018 06:21:08 +0800
```

Question: Should there actually be something in the square brackets of b'BODY[]'? Is that why I get 'Message body is None'?